# Message: Configured database connection is persistent. Aborting

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-connection, codeigniter-3

Codeigniter 2 to 3 version after upgrading, I get this error..
Why would that be?

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Exception

Message: Configured database connection is persistent. Aborting.

Filename: /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/app/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 94

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/app/application/core/MY_Controller.php
Line: 11
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/app/application/core/MY_Controller.php
Line: 52
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/app/application/controllers/Dashboard.php
Line: 7
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/application/index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue, and found that it was just a matter of changing a setting:

Modify your database.php config file and turn 'pconnect' to false. As part of the CI 3 Framework, it would be part of this array:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'pconnect' => FALSE // This value
);
```

Or if your config file looks more like the CI 2 version:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

A bit of searching seems to suggest that the database doesn't like a persistent connection, possible because of security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Disable caching in database.php file, define caching folder in database.php by

```
'cachedir' => APPPATH.'cache/db/',
```

setting  and only use

```
$this->db->cache_on();
```

command where you want your database query being cached.

Don't forget to use

```
$this->db->cache_off();
```

after select queries for unwanted cached results.

Answer (score 1):

It seems  like codeigniter 3.0 doesn't support sessions using database, when persistent is enabled.
form: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session#session-preferences

> However, there are some conditions that must be met:
>
> Only your default database connection (or the one that you access as
>   $this->db from your controllers) can be used. You must have the Query
>   Builder enabled. You can NOT use a persistent connection. You can NOT
>   use a connection with the cache_on setting enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that FALSE goes out without quotes.If you use 'FALSE', the database driver will take that as a true boolean. The system expects you to use FALSE directly, without quotes. So, unset pconnect instead of using 'FALSE' in order to default to FALSE, or use FALSE as a value if you like to keep things ordered :)

```
 * Persistent connection flag
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $pconnect        = FALSE;
```