# Unable to locate an appunto-auth model in CI 3

Tags: php, model-view-controller, authentication, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to integrate appunto system to my application so I followed the full installation structure from the documentation but all time I got the next message :

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: RuntimeException

Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Pathmodel

Filename: /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/git-backup_releasecandidate_net/system/core/Loader.php

Line Number: 344

Backtrace:

File: /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/git-backup_releasecandidate_net/application/libraries/appunto-auth/Appunto_auth.php
Line: 24
Function: model

File: /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/git-backup_releasecandidate_net/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: What is line 24 of `APPPATH.'libraries/appunto-auth/Appunto_auth.php'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following [this](https://github.com/BillClinton/Appunto-Auth) guide. You may need to change these lines in Appunto_auth library class.

```
    $this->CI->load->model('appunto-auth/pathmodel');
    $this->CI->load->model('appunto-auth/usermodel');
```

You may remove the appunto-auth folder from the path to the models since they will no longer be in that directory as we have moved it according to the guide.

```
    $this->CI->load->model('pathmodel');
    $this->CI->load->model('usermodel');
```

You may do the same if your app screams about the helper and config files on lines 22 and 15.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying me. i made the modifications but i got thise error :
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Exception

Message: Configured database connection is persistent. Aborting.

Filename: /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/git-backup2_releasecandidate_net/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 94

Backtrace:

File: /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/git-backup2_releasecandidate_net/application/libraries/appunto-auth/Appunto_auth.php
Line: 19
Function: library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29446898/message-configured-database-connection-is-persistent-aborting has your solution